# Jquery ajax reaches success without parsing json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is so weird and opposite to what I usually experience with jquery's ajax function.

I have the following javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/myService.svc/DoAction",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
        if (res.ErrorCode == 0) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    },
    error: function (res) {
        //do something
    },
    complete: function () {
        //do something
    }
});
```

My service builds a response in json format. My response header:

```
Response            HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
Content-Length      157
Content-Type        application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I reach `Success`... but the response from the service is not parsed to a javascript object... I receive a plain String like this:

```
[{"ErrorCode": "0", "Data": {"title": "test", "data": [{"name": "someName", "id": "1234-12345678-abcd-1234"}]}, "ErrorMessage": ""}]
```

How is it reaching `success` while not parsing the json string to a javascript object?

As specified in the Jquery documentation:

```
[$.ajax]
[dataType]
"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.
```

**EDIT:**

I tried returning an invalid json string and I still enter `success`... I feel like I'm missing something really obvious!

Comment: If the AJAX call has been completed (found the server, got a connection, etc), it's a success. If the data being retrieved is incorrect, it's a totally different thing.

Comment: **success** Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR ) A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, _the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn._ This is an Ajax Event. [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: What do you mean by "not parsing"? If you do `console.log(res);` as the first line of the success anonymous function, can you expand it out?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Quoting from the Jquery documentation: "Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown." It is my experience as well that either the json is parsed to a javascript object and thus we enter `success` or it fails to parse to an object and we enter `error`. What is happening here is that the response is not parsed as json into a javascript object, I receive a plain old string, but still get `success`

Comment: Have you tried @ChrisForrence suggestion?

Comment: @ChrisForrence To answer your second question, no, I cannot expand it out in the console as I receive a simple String. By "not parsing" I mean that jquery is supposed to parse the string response to a javascript object (as I quoted to MelanciaUK from the Jquery documentation), but does not. I get a String object.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes, see my response to his comment

Comment: I don't see any issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4rfrgjr8/

Comment: You _can_ legally get back a string from a response. Out of curiousity though, is your application intending to return an Array? (that's what it's doing; surrounded by the square brackets)

Comment: @ChrisForrence I'm still deciding on the exact format for the response... it probably won't be an array... but it was at the time I posted the question. :P  And yeah, I get that a string can legally be returned but I had built a json in valid json format and I was returning it expecting it to be parsed to a javascript object... I found my mistake (see the answer I posted) and it had nothing to do with the jquery end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...I knew I was missing something obvious!

My service is a C# WCF and I was returning a `String` in the service.

My `web.config` contained the following, which I found online as part of a tutorial on building a WCF web service:

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Note the `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` which made sure that no matter what I sent, it would be formatted "properly".

The solution was two-fold:

1. remove the `defaultOutgoingResponseFormat` and `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` and simply control those thigns myself. [They seemed appropriate... :( ]
2. Return a `ResponseObject` and not a `String`.

Someone downvote the question earlier... I kind of agree with that downvote now. :(